# Рекурсивный обход объекта JS

Tags: javascript, объекты, рекурсия, key

Необходимо получить массив из всех элементов "key" на всех уровнях вложенности с помощью рекурсии JS.

```
const data = [
    {
        key: '1.001',
        data: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [
            {
                key: '1.002',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
            {
                key: '1.003',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
            {
                key: '1.004',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        key: '1.005',
                        data: {
                            id: '1',
                            name: 'qwe',
                        },
                        children: null,
                    },
                    {
                        key: '1.006',
                        data: {
                            id: '1',
                            name: 'qwe',
                        },
                        children: null,
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: '2.001',
        data: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [
            {
                key: '2.002',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
            {
                key: '2.003',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: и какой должен быть результат для приведенного объекта?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1.001',
    data: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '1.002',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.003',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.004',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [{
            key: '1.005',
            data: {
              id: '1',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
          {
            key: '1.006',
            data: {
              id: '1',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: '2.001',
    data: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '2.002',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '2.003',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
    ]
  }
]

function keys(data) {
  const a = []
  void(function foo(d) {
    for (let {
        key,
        children
      } of d) {
      a.push(key)
      if (children) {
        foo(children)
      }
    }
  })(data)
  return a
}

console.log(keys(data))
```

Comment: зачем тут void нужен?

Comment: @Grundy Скорее не `void`, а скобки которые необязательны после `void`. Без `void` точку с запятой пришлось бы ставить.

Comment: :-D то есть, чтобы не писать один символ, решил написать 4? :)

Comment: @Grundy Есть такое дело - _привычка_. Настройки моего редактора не позволяют ставить `;` в конце(только с дополнительным пробелом), я не использую их - не нравится. А спереди редактор сбивает форматирование. Хотя иногда, конечно же, я их использую.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Так как надо получить плоский список можно воспользоваться методом [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), массивы, возвращаемые коллбэком переданным в данный метод, будут объединены в один.

Для обхода в глубину достаточно применить ту же функцию к массиву `.children`

в итоге получим:

```
data.flatMap(function traverse(el) {
  return [el.key].concat( // объединяем значение ключа в текущем элементе
    el.children?.flatMap(traverse) || [] // с ключами в дочерних
  )
})
```

В коде выше используется [?. (Optional chaining)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) позволяющий обойтись без проверки наличия свойства `children`. В случае отсутствия данного свойства будет возвращено значение `undefined`, которого будет заменено на `[]` с помощью логического `ИЛИ`.

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1.001',
    data: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '1.002',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.003',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.004',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [{
            key: '1.005',
            data: {
              id: '1',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
          {
            key: '1.006',
            data: {
              id: '1',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: '2.001',
    data: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '2.002',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '2.003',
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
    ]
  }
]

console.log(data.flatMap(function traverse(el) {
  return [el.key].concat(el.children?.flatMap(traverse) || [])
}));
```

Comment: Я уж и забыл, что flatMap существует))) А про Optional chaining  наверное стоит упомянуть про то, на какие браузеры. А то он довольно новый

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, его кстати уже все последние имплементировали, так что можно считать, что везде есть :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {
        key: '1.001',
        data: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [
            {
                key: '1.002',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
            {
                key: '1.003',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
            {
                key: '1.004',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        key: '1.005',
                        data: {
                            id: '1',
                            name: 'qwe',
                        },
                        children: null,
                    },
                    {
                        key: '1.006',
                        data: {
                            id: '1',
                            name: 'qwe',
                        },
                        children: null,
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: '2.001',
        data: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [
            {
                key: '2.002',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
            {
                key: '2.003',
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'qwe',
                },
                children: null,
            },
        ]
    }
];


function test(data) {
    let result = [];
    
    data.forEach(el => {
        result.push(el.key);

        if (el.children) 
            result.push(...test(el.children));        
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(test(data));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!